# Blazor Server, using language from Browser-Settings

Tags: localization, blazor-server-side

I am totally confused...

In my Blazor Server App I tried to use the language that is set in the browser.
This tutorial from MS confuses me completely, because here is constantly talking about adding something to "Program.cs".

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-from-the-accept-language-header](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-from-the-accept-language-header)

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization()

and

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .AddSupportedCultures(new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" })
    .AddSupportedUICultures(new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" }));
```

There is no place in my program.cs where I could add this.
Instead I use the startup.cs and add this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization();   //  <=== this Line
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();           
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            //services.AddAuthorizationCore();  16.05.2023 ersetzt durch AddAuthentication und AddAuthorization, geht immer noch.
            services.AddHttpClient(); //04.05.2023 für den download der Auswertungen
            services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
        }


and

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env ) //, SessionController sessionController)
        {
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()   //<== this lines
                .AddSupportedCultures(new[] { "sv-SE", "de-DE" })
                .AddSupportedUICultures(new[] { "sv-SE", "de-DE" })
                );

     if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });

            MyConfiguration(); //My own Config.
        }
```

If I understood correctly, this should be enough for my application to be displayed in the language that is set in the browser.
But this does not happen.

Only when I add the following lines, it works:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
                    new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("de-DE")); //Fall-Back-Sprache, quasi.
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

//Beginning of my solution, i dont understand ;)
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
                {
                    //liest aus dem Request die Browser-Einstellung für Sprachen aus
                    var userLanguages = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
                    var primaryLanguage = userLanguages.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
                    if (primaryLanguage == "sv") primaryLanguage = "sv-SE";

                   
                    var userCulture = new CultureInfo(primaryLanguage);
                    return await Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(userCulture?.Name ?? supportedCultures[0].Name));
                }));
            });


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

…
```

I don't understand why I still need to add this code.
I also don't understand if this is the right place for it.
I don't understand why the instructions keep talking about adding something to program.cs.
I don't understand anything anymore :)

Aside:
I use .resx files for de-DE and sv-SE with the language resources.
Accessed via:

```
@using MyResource;

@MyResource.someKey
```

or in code-behind:

```
using MyResources
String something = MyResource.someKey
```

I am also confused why I need "Localizer" (@Localizer["someKey"], but that's another topic....

Can someone please help me understand why adding these lines is not enough to use the browser's language?

```
   app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()   //<== this lines
                .AddSupportedCultures(new[] { "sv-SE", "de-DE" })
                .AddSupportedUICultures(new[] { "sv-SE", "de-DE" })
                );
```

Comment: It sounds like you are working with an old Blazor project - newer projects removed `startup.cs` and just use `program.cs` - you are fine to continue using `startup.cs`

Comment: From .NET 6 there is no Startup.cs, only Program.cs. More on this topic [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdhFw1VSowg).

Comment: @LuciusAgarthy You can still use Startup if it suits to you, there's nothing wrong with that. They even thought about it by keeping the `webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()` method that you can call within the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`